# To check if (0,0) is local minima for$F ( x, y) = x (x - 2y^{2}) $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hello Thanks for your time

$F ( x, y) = x (x - 2y^{2}) $ . I have applied second derivative test which does not give any result .

By looking at function i see that  when x is greater than  $2y^{2} $ , f is positive otherwise negative  , So according to me should be saddle point  . But textbook states it is minima .I need help.So much Thanks .So long !

Comment: Hint: Consider intersections of the surface $z=x(x-2y^2)$ with *vertical* planes $ax+by=0$.

Comment: @JankoBracic i don't understand . Can you please explain

Comment: If you typed the question correctly I'd agree with you and say that this point fails to be a local minima. And you almost clearly stated the reason of that.

Comment: @Evgeny i have typed question correctly ,but ì am not sure whether my reasoning  is correct\adequate

Comment: If you know that the value of function at point $(0,0)$ is zero and you can show that in any neighbourhood there are points with function values of different signs -- then your reasoning is of course correct and adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $F$ is zero on the $y$-axis $x=0$ and on the parabola $x=2y^2$. When you cross one of these curves $F$ changes sign. To be explicit: $F(x,0)=x^2>0$ when $\>x>0$, and  $$F(y^2,y)=y^2(y^2-2y^2)=-y^4<0$$ 
when $y\ne0$. It follows that $F$ assumes as well positive as negative values in any neighborhood of $(0,0)$. Since $F(0,0)=0$ this implies that $F$ has neither a local maximum nor a local minimum at $(0,0)$.

The second derivative test is inconclusive in this example, since $(0,0)$ is a *degenerate critical point* of $F$. In such cases only a an actual discussion of ${\rm sgn}(f)$ in the neighborhood of the critical point admits  a definitive answer.